# Vue3 cannot use exported data inside component

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

Basically, I am trying to create a reactive array in vue3. A button click would increase the length of said array. This is my code.

```
            <div class="package-item" v-for="n in arraySize"></div>
```

```
export default {
  methods: {
    data () {
      return {
        arraySize: 1
      }
    },
    arrayAppend () {
      if (this.arraySize) {
        this.arraySize++
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the error I get

```
Property 'arraySize' does not exist on type '{ data(): { arraySize: number; }; textareacharct(): void; addInline(key: any): void; hoverRender(): number; arrayAppend(): void;
```

I think Vue is going to kill me. Any help would be fantastic.

I tried using defineComponent after export default, and when I included
`import { defineComponent } from 'vue'`
I kept getting an error saying
`could not find defineComponent` for which I couldn't find a fix ANYWHERE on the internet.

Comment: Ignore the "could not find defineComponent" error I was getting. I was able to fix that. Using ```export default defineComponent({...})``` still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I included `data ()` inside my methods like a fool. Lots of headache for naught.